# How to use a JWT token inside an httpOnly cookie to call a restricted api endpoint

Tags: javascript, jwt, next.js, fetch, next-auth

I am using `next.js` and `next-auth` to login users against an API. if the login is successful, an httpOnly cookie is set to the browser. The cookie name is `__Secure-next-auth.session-token` and this is the value (no worries is fake data):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImV5SjBlWEFpT2lKS1YxUWlMQ0poYkdjaU9pSlNVekkxTmlKOS5leUpwWVhRaU9qRTJNelkyTXprMk5EY3NJbVY0Y0NJNk1UWXpOalkwTXpJME55d2ljbTlzWlhNaU9sc2lVazlNUlY5VlUwVlNJbDBzSW5WelpYSnVZVzFsSWpvaVpYSnVZVE01UUhkbFltVnlMbU52YlNKOS5obWZqQ3NBWDFsWHdCMWdUNDlRUFdRWjM4OG52b2pKTlJMaDI1d3RCTVlBSHhQN2RxelpsZWFzTWZSVXZqSmJXVjdRUldYZnRYYUJFOG1pTEE4Y1JsNTVlZUd5bE9MbHhoQVRORTZPNjZLQjdzMXhPczB6Nmg1TXFadnlRa3JhcjFfYnF5WXgzQzBZdXVHWk1NWEFMUDJPS3Q5Sjk2dVdZVF9KT25USzNhRTZEQnpqaWF5OWw2alludExLZkUyQUhKMVgwVE9UcEN3QjBHeFB3d1otVWh0NjU5NEtLZS0yakpkQmhqd185VGJWSUVFaV9SbF8zMDFabmhHdDZZYzN6SE9WNm9WSk4zOTBSTXFrM283cWRONkw0R0JKb1g5NzQ1NkNJLTVFSllJN3ozcXpjVEwtZUNGc3luRkJIZHEzNnF2TFd3aDJpeDVkTy1MVDU1cXE5VlEiLCJpYXQiOjE2MzY2NTcwNjYsImV4cCI6MTYzOTI0OTA2Nn0.QGRPwJSECbFfkvUyn8h-gInELUzGHsxBFrnMAW9zEfqCuHwJRkT1aunqFt7g5aWp6DZrSUHaKvp3OJr-0xwUzw
```

if I decode this jwt, I get an object where one of the properties is `jwt` and the value is the token I received from the API.

Can anyone please tell me

- if this is the correct format and
- how can I use it in a fetch call to restricted api endpoints?

At the monent I am just doing a fetch call with this options

```
    method: 'GET',
    'cors': 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'same-origin'
```

but no luck the response I get is

```
 [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://localhost/countries',
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
```

Comment: Where are you making the request from? If it's done from the browser then the way you've setup your `fetch` call will automatically send the cookies with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check your API documentation to see what it's expecting.  Often, for example, you'll attach the token to the `Authorization` header

Comment: fine but how can I read that cookie to pass the token? afaik js can't read a httpOnly cookie.

Comment: Sorry, just seen this.  The cookie will be sent with your request, where the server can read it.  this is normally the approach used for refresh tokens